# Whitespace after class def in Python

Tags: python, coding-style

Someone recently pointed out that when writing Python code I have a tendency to put a blank line between a class definition and the class body.

E.g.

```
class A(object):

    def f(self):
        blah()
```

I notice that flake8 does not point this out as an issue. The PEP style guide doesn't seem to cover this case, or at the very best it leaves this open to interpretation (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines).

Wondering if anyone knows if there is a preference, or is it OK with and without the blank line.

Cheers

Comment: I'd say it comes down to preference.  I put a blank line after each separate code block to make it more readable.  As long as the PEP guidelines don't expressly discourage it, I wouldn't worry about it.  Stick with a style that works best for you, and whoever else may work on that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Class_and_static_methods

I would agree with JPeroutek about personal preferences, but if your code is particularly long you may want to take those extra spaces between classes and methods out. I use spaces for legibility purposes, but some people do not. At the end of the end it is all personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm, the default setting for spaces around a class declaration is 1 (that could signify convention).  But as previously stated, preference reigns here.

Comment: Do you mean that PyCharm will insert a blank line after `class Blah(object):`?

Comment: It doesn't automatically, but it will flag it (unless you turn that specific flag off or change the number of lines manually)